# sending div id through button click java-script method parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can anyone please tell me how to send div id through button click java-script parameter.
Here in the below code the main div id **'ricId_1'** and the class name **"ric_class1 rico_class0 ric1_class1 ric2_class3"** is created dynamically has to be send through javascript method **cancel('divid')** in the button click.The div id is not static.

```
<div id="ricId_1" class="ric_class1 rico_class0 ric1_class1 ric2_class3" style="width: 730px; left: 309px; top: 71.5px; z-index: 13000; display: block;">
        <div class="ricTitle">
            :
        </div>

        <div class="ricModal ng-scope" style="height: auto;">
            :
        <div>

        <div>
            <div ng-controller="Manage" class="ng-scope">
                <div class="ricG ricAlign">
                    <div class="ricGrid"><div class="ricGridTable">
                     :
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div align="center" class="row btn-group">
            <button onclick="cancel('divid')" class="ricButton" type="button" id="sss" ric:loaded="true">Close</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: the `divid` should be equal to the clicked button id?

Comment: @BeNdErR actually `divid` is been created dynamically if it is static we can assign .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the button to cancel and use that id to get the closes ancestor with class `ric_class1 rico_class0 ric1_class1 ric2_class3` having id `ricId_1`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/5/)**

Html

```
<button onclick="cancel(this)" class="ricButton" type="button" id="sss" ric:loaded="true">Close</button>
```

Javascript

```
function cancel(btn)
{
     ricId_1 = $(btn).closest('ric_class1 rico_class0.ric1_class1 ric2_class3');
     //or
     ricId_1 = $(btn).parent().parent();

}
```

Comment: but here `ric_class1 rico_class0.ric1_class1 ric2_class3` is also dynamic

Comment: You can use parent().parent() then

Comment: there all div's are properly closed http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/2/.....still giving undefined

Comment: Check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/3/ or here, http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="ricId_1" class="ric_class1 rico_class0 ric1_class1 ric2_class3" style="width: 730px; left: 309px; top: 71.5px; z-index: 13000; display: block;">
  <div align="center" class="row btn-group">
    <button class="ricButton" type="button" id="sss" ric:loaded="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.ricButton').on('click', function(){
    var getId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    alert(getId);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5FQ92/)**

Comment: because your divs are not close properly. check you html code.

Comment: how bout this here all div's are properly closed http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/2/.....still giving undefined

Comment: in this you have added two more parent for $(this) object. that's why it's showing undefined. One more thing in current fiddle no need to close the br tag. it's self closing tag </br> not '<br style=""></br>'

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#sss").click(cancel(divid ));
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `this` to the function call and retrieve the `id` later

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/PrX52/

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="cancel(this)" class="ricButton" type="button" id="sss" ric:loaded="true">Close</button>
```

**JS**

```
function cancel(el){
    alert(el.id);
};
```